# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier を解決したいです

Tags: python, python3, macos

先週末よりPythonを始めたばかりの初心者です。

データを定期的に取り込み、定点的に分析するツールを作りたく、調べながら、その雛形を作成中です。詳しい人でしたら、すぐに原因がわかる内容かもしれませんが、お助けくださると感謝します。

#### これまでに試したこと

エラーを潰しながら進んでおりますが、現コードを実行しますと、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

```
File "<ipython-input-18-06795348b04f>", line 93
    model3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=3, random_state=0)
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

#### 現在のコード

```
import pandas as pd
#Pandas.ExcelFile でデータを読み込む
input_book = pd.ExcelFile('FIFA19_data.xlsx')

input_sheet_name = input_book.sheet_names
num_sheet = len(input_sheet_name)
print(input_sheet_name)
print("sheet の数:", num_sheet)
input_sheet_df = input_book.parse(input_sheet_name[0])

#GK のデータのみを外す
input_sheet_df = input_sheet_df[input_sheet_df['Position']!= "GK"]
#最初の10行のみを表示する
input_sheet_df.head(10)

import numpy as np

#データを読み込む
age=input_sheet_df.Age #年齢
overall=input_sheet_df.Overall #総合能力
wage=input_sheet_df.Wage #給与
PreferredFoot=input_sheet_df.PreferredFoot #利き足
Reputation=input_sheet_df.Reputation #レピュテーション
least_contract=input_sheet_df.least_contract #残りの契約年数
crossing=input_sheet_df.Crossing #クロス精度
Finishing=input_sheet_df.Finishing #フィニッシュ精度
heading=input_sheet_df.HeadingAccuracy #ヘディング精度
ShortPassing=input_sheet_df.ShortPassing #ショートパス精度
Dribbling=input_sheet_df.Dribbling #ドリブルの精度
Curve=input_sheet_df.Curve #カーブの精度
FKAccuracy=input_sheet_df.FKAccuracy #FK の精度
LongPassing=input_sheet_df.LongPassing #ロングパスの精度
BallControl=input_sheet_df.BallControl #ボールコントロール
Acceleration=input_sheet_df.Acceleration #飛び出し
SprintSpeed=input_sheet_df.SprintSpeed #スプリントスピード
Agility=input_sheet_df.Agility #アジリティ
Reactions=input_sheet_df.Reactions #リアクション
Balance=input_sheet_df.Balance #バランス
ShotPower=input_sheet_df.ShotPower #シュートパワー
stamina=input_sheet_df.Stamina #スタミナ
Jumping=input_sheet_df.Jumping #ジャンプ
Strength=input_sheet_df.Strength #ストレングス
LongShots=input_sheet_df.LongShots #ロングシュート
Aggression=input_sheet_df.Aggression #アグレッション
Interceptions=input_sheet_df.Interceptions #インターセプト
Positioning=input_sheet_df.Positioning
Vision=input_sheet_df.Vision
Penalties=input_sheet_df.Penalties
Composure=input_sheet_df.Composure
Marking=input_sheet_df.Marking
StandingTackle=input_sheet_df.StandingTackle
SlidingTackle=input_sheet_df.SlidingTackle

#利用するパラメータを指定する
equation_df2=pd.concat([wage, age, PreferredFoot, Reputation, least_contract, \
                        crossing, Finishing, heading, ShortPassing, Dribbling, Curve, FKAccuracy, \
                       LongPassing, BallControl, Acceleration, SprintSpeed, Agility, Reactions, \
                       Balance, ShotPower, stamina, Jumping, Strength, LongShots, Aggression, \
                       Interceptions, Positioning, Vision, Penalties, Composure, Marking, \
                       StandingTackle, SlidingTackle], axis=1)

#被説明変数として利用するものを取り出す
wage2 = pd.DataFrame(equation_df2.Wage)
#被説明変数を抜き取る
x_list2 = equation_df2.drop("Wage",1)

from sklearn import preprocessing, linear_model
import sklearn
import seaborn as sns

#データの整形を行う
#データの標準化を行う
sc=preprocessing.StandardScaler()
sc.fit(x_list2)

X=sc.transform(x_list2)

#相関係数を確認する

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(30,24))
sns.heatmap(x_list2.pct_change().corr(), annot=True, cmap='Blues')

from sklearn import model_selection
#学習データとテストデータに分割する
#分割する割合は2:8 で作業する
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, wage, test_size=0.2, ramdom_state=0)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

#決定木分析を, X_train 値と Y_train 値に基づき行う
model3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=3, random_state=0)　
model3.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print('正解率(train):{:.3f}'.format(model3.score(X_train, Y_train)))
print('正解率(train):{:.3f}'.format(model3.score(X_test, Y_test)))
```

#### 読み込むデータ (Dropboxリンク)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/41lap8qzcxez33o/FIFA19_data.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

問題のエラーは、単純にその行の末尾に全角空白が入っているからだと思われます。

```
model3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=3, random_state=0)
```

他にもそうしたことが無いか確かめて修正してみてください。

---

ちなみにこの辺の記事を参考にして、ある程度自動的にソースコードを見易い表示・整形・エラー検出などをしてくれるようにすれば、時間と手間の短縮になるのでは？
[MacでJupyter Notebookに拡張機能を入れて使いやすくする](https://memowo.com/study/memopy/jupyter-notebook-extensions/)
[[作業効率化] Jupyterの拡張機能を全部調べてみた](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/88161c806197a0b84174)
[Jupyter 知っておくと少し便利なTIPS集](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/d7dccb798f0b9c8b1ec5)

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます。全角空白はおっしゃる通りでした。
頂いたリンク記事も拝見して、Code prettify や Hinterland を有効にしてみました。
深謝しています。